# Is there a way to read Excel file without workbook with openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlsx

I am using `Python 2.7` & `openpyxl==2.5.11`.

For files with valid workbook I am reading the content with this code:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('my_file.xlsx', read_only=True)
ws = wb.worksheets[1]
rows = ws.rows
```

Now, a tester provided an old file to me, which doesn't have valid workbook part and raises this error:

`IOError: File contains no valid workbook part`

in this line `ws = wb.worksheets[1]`

I couldn't find an example how to read data for such files in the openpyxl  documentation.

I managed to read the file using `pandas`:

`data = pandas.read_excel('my_file.xlxs')`

Is there a way to read the file with `openpyxl`, because I already use `openpyxl` in my app and wouldn't like to migrate completely to `pandas`, nor use both in different places in my app. Ideally I would like to use single lib for Excel file manipulation across all application services and if possible I would like to avoid transitioning form `openpyxl` to `pandas`, because I cannot estimate how big effort that transition would require, nor whether all my use cases would work out of the box with `pandas`.

Comment: Would you be able to use Excel itself? i.e. are you on Windows? Python could can be used to automate this.

Comment: @MartinEvans no, I am not on Windows and don't have Excel installed. Our server is Ubuntu, so this doesn't look like an option.

Comment: Without a workbook.xml part then the file is not a valid OOXML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [The Pineapple's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53472545/is-there-a-way-to-read-excel-file-without-workbook-with-openpyxl/53472682#53472682) and [Jon Clements's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53472545/is-there-a-way-to-read-excel-file-without-workbook-with-openpyxl#comment93816288_53472682), I came up with a solution which reads data into `xlrd` workbook and then creates `openpyxl` Workbook as a result of the function. This helps my use case, because I already use the `openpyxl` Workbook in multiple places in my application. Here is the code:

```
import xlrd
from openpyxl import Workbook


def open_excel_without_workbook_part(filename):
    xlrd_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(filename=filename)
    xlrd_worksheet = xlrd_workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
    nrows = xlrd_worksheet.nrows
    ncols = xlrd_worksheet.ncols

    # create a xlsx file using openpyxl
    openpyxl_book = Workbook()
    openpyxl_worksheet = openpyxl_book.active

    for row in xrange(0, nrows):
        for col in xrange(0, ncols):
            openpyxl_worksheet.cell(row=row + 1, column=col + 1).value = xlrd_worksheet.cell_value(row, col)

    return openpyxl_book


if __name__ == '__main__':
    workbook = open_excel_without_workbook_part('file-without-valid-workbook.xlsx')

    sheet = workbook.worksheets[0]
    for row in sheet.rows:
        print '\t'.join([cell.value for cell in row])
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be exactly what you are looking for, but you could read excel the file using pandas, then convert it to openpyxl rows using [openpyxl.utils.dataframe module](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.utils.dataframe.html).

**Example implementation**

```
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook

# pandas code 
xl = pd.ExcelFile("dummydata.xlsx")
df = xl.parse(xl.sheet_names[0])

# openpyxl code
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=True, header=True):
    ws.append(r)
```

Comment: It seems I could use this fix as a workaround for my problem. However, I would prefer to avoid using `pandas` if possible (to avoid having 2 dependencies). Thank you for the answer, if I don't find cleaner solution I'll try to integrate this fix into my solution.

Comment: @giliev I think underneath `pandas` also uses the [`xlrd`](https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/) lib. for reading... have you tried seeing if that reads your .xlsx succesfully?